# Schedule Android function when App is closed at specific time

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, notifications, background-task

I want to create an App that throws a notification everyday at 20pm. For that I need to time a function that gets executed every day at 20pm. Whats the best way to solve this? What should I use?
This is the function I want to execute:

```
private fun throwNotification() {
    notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

    notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(channelId, description, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
    notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
    notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.RED
    notificationChannel.enableVibration(true)
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)

    builder = Notification.Builder(this, channelId)
        .setContentTitle("Test")
        .setContentText("This is a test notification")
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setChannelId(channelId)

    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build())
}
```

Comment: idk maybe https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager

Comment: You need a background service that runs every time and checks every hour if it is 20 PM and executes your task.

Comment: If you want a guarantee that the task is executed in my opinion this is the solution.

Comment: I don't like that the background service runs all the time, isn't there a better solution?

Comment: If you want a guaranteed execution it is the way or give it a try Alarm Manager.

Comment: @pad AlarmManager is the way to go. The only other way that I can think of is to implement Push-Notifications with Firebase. However, you'd need your own server with script, that using your Firebase key would send notifications and all that would be periodically executed with crontab. Alarm Manager sounds much simpler in this case.

Comment: Firebase would be no option for me, I want to go only App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be concerned following tasks.

1. The function should be executed at exactly 20pm.
2. #1 should be repeated everyday.
3. The notification should be pushed even if the app is closed.
4. Above issues should not matter whether the device restarts.

The solution I found is following and that requires the app should be launched at least once.

#1~3 can be implemented by [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager).
At app's first launch, call following code that registers **alarmIntent**.

```kotlin
private var alarmMgr: AlarmManager? = null
private lateinit var alarmIntent: PendingIntent

alarmMgr = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
alarmIntent = Intent(context, YourAlarmReceiver::class.java).let { intent ->
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0)
}

// Set the alarm to start at 20:00.
val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
    timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20)
    set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
    set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
}

// setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
// 1 day.
alarmMgr?.setRepeating(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        calendar.timeInMillis,
        1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
        alarmIntent
)
```

Here, **YourAlarmReceiver**'s onReceive() will be called at every 20pm by **alarmIntent**.
So what you have to do is only calling **throwNotification()** inside this onReceive().

#4 is also easy, that being said, it can be implemented by listening to BOOT_COMPLETED event.